# Python Scrapy gets stuck after 40k requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

My scrapy spider is getting stuck after 40k requests.

I am new to scrapy. Searching around, I wonder if the problem has to do with using the default `parse` method name and `start_urls`.

I am using `custom_settings` to speed things up. If a URL doesn't resolve within a few seconds, move on and don't retry.

Spider code:

```
import scrapy, re, pandas as pd, os, logging
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import SfscrapeItem
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging 

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, '../resources/scraping_urls_1.1.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0)

keywords = ['canidae', 'felidae', 'cat', 'cattle', 'dog', 'donkey', 'goat', 'guinea pig', 'horse', 'pig', 'rabbit']

class sfSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name='sfspider'

    custom_settings = {
        'DNS_TIMEOUT': 10,
        'DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT':10,
        'RETRY_ENABLED': False,
        'REDIRECT_MAX_TIMES': 2,
    }

    configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename='log.txt',
        format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
        level=logging.INFO
    )

    #just the first 75k for now...
    start_urls = df.url.to_list()[:75000] 

    def parse(self, response):

        response_body = response.body.decode('utf-8')

        url = response.url
        domain = url.split('/')[2]

        item = SfscrapeItem()
        item['url'] = url
        item['domain'] = domain
        item['status'] = response.status
        item['matches'] = [str(len(re.findall(keyword, response_body, re.IGNORECASE))) for keyword in keywords]
        
        yield item
```

Here is the log at the point when it is stuck

```
INFO: Crawled 40940 pages (at 565 pages/min), scraped 16473 items (at 243 items/min)
INFO: Crawled 40940 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 16473 items (at 0 items/min)
INFO: Crawled 40940 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 16473 items (at 0 items/min)
INFO: Crawled 40940 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 16473 items (at 0 items/min)
INFO: Crawled 40940 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 16473 items (at 0 items/min)
INFO: Crawled 40940 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 16473 items (at 0 items/min)
```

And here is the output of `stats.get_stats()` and `prefs()` after it is stuck.
[image]

Comment: Did you try to diagnose the problem? Did you consider the possibility that the website you're trying to scrape doesn't want you to keep scraping it? Did you consider the possibility of something wrong with your internet connection?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like You started to receive `DNSLookupError`

 as you have this`downloader/exception_type_count/twisted.internet.DNSLookupError: 5109` in stats on minutes with `...pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped x items (at 0 items/min)`

LogStats extention (module that print `INFO: Crawled X pages (at X pages/min), scraped X items (at X items/min)` to log) count only received responses (it doesn't count received exceptions).

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the suggestion.